# Enumerate within a multicolumn cell using tabularx

Tags: enumerate, tabularx, multicolumn, enumitem, vspace

I would like to add a subitem with an indent to an item inside a table. I have shown a working example. As you can see, the subitem overlaps with the horizontal line of the following cell. The sub item is to be numbered as 4.1 instead of 5. In addition, I would like the space between the text and top horizontal line to be the same for the two columns when one of them contains a list (See row 1 and 2, the text in the two columns have different spacing with respect to the top horizontal line).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1.11in,right=0.75in,top=0.5in,bottom=1.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx} %font
\usepackage{soul} %underline
\setul{}{1pt} %underline thickness
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{label=\arabic*.,
                 nosep, wide, leftmargin=*,
                 before=\vspace{-0.37\baselineskip},
                 after =\vspace{-0.85\baselineskip}}
                 
\title{{\normalsize \textbf{\ul{PROGRESS REPORT}}}\vspace{-2.5em}}
\date{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\hsize=1.3\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X|>{\hsize=0.7\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X|}    
    \hline
        \begin{mylist}[start=1]
            \item Project Title:\newline \lipsum[75]
        \end{mylist}
        & File No: \newline XXX/YYYY/NNNNNNNN \\
    \hline
        \begin{mylist}[start=2]
            \item PI (Name \& Address): \newline Dr. Some Long Name \newline Some Research Institute, Street Name, City Name, District Name, State Name, Country, Pincode 
        \end{mylist}
        & Date of Birth:\newline DD/MM/YYYY\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=2\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X|}{
       \begin{mylist}[start=4] 
            \item Broad area of Research: Physics
            \begin{mylist}[label*=\arabic*.] 
                \item Sub area of Research: Superconductivity
            \end{mylist}
       \end{mylist}}\\
    \hline
    
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=2\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X|}{
       \begin{mylist}[start=5] 
            \item Project Proposal: \newline 
            \lipsum[2-4]
       \end{mylist}}\\
    \hline
        Date of Start: DD/MM/YYYY & Project Cost: xxxxxxx \\
    \hline
        \multirow[t]{3}{*}{Date of Completion: DD/MM/YYYY} &  Total Expense xxxxxxx  \\
         & Conumables - xxxxxxxx\\
         & Travel - xxxxxxxx\\  
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
  
\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image: This results in:]

Answer (score 0):

The subitem without subnumber is due to `\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{1}` I changed it to `\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{2}`.

For the rest, I suggest using `tabularray`.

Are the numbers that go from 2 to 4, without 3, wanted?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1.11in,right=0.75in,top=0.5in,bottom=1.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx} %font
\usepackage{soul} %underline
\setul{}{1pt} %underline thickness
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[mylist]{label=\arabic*.,
                 nosep, wide, leftmargin=*,}  
                 
\title{{\normalsize \textbf{\ul{PROGRESS REPORT}}}\vspace{-2.5em}}
\date{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
    hlines, vlines,
    colspec={X[1.3]X[.7]},
    measure=vbox,stretch=-1,
    rowsep=4pt,
    }    
    \begin{mylist}
        \item Project Title:\newline \lipsum[75]
    \end{mylist}
    & {File No:\\ XXX/YYYY/NNNNNNNN} \\
    \begin{mylist}[start=2]
        \item PI (Name \& Address): \newline Dr. Some Long Name \newline Some Research Institute, Street Name, City Name, District Name, State Name, Country, Pincode 
    \end{mylist}
    & {Date of Birth:\\ DD/MM/YYYY}\\
    \SetCell[c=2]{l}
    \begin{mylist}[start=4] 
        \item Broad area of Research: Physics
        \begin{mylist}[label*=\arabic*.] 
            \item Sub area of Research: Superconductivity
        \end{mylist}
   \end{mylist}\\
   \SetCell[c=2]{j, wd=\linewidth-\parindent}
   \begin{mylist}[start=5] 
        \item Project Proposal: \newline 
        \lipsum[2-4]
   \end{mylist}\\
   Date of Start: DD/MM/YYYY & Project Cost: xxxxxxx \\
   Date of Completion: DD/MM/YYYY & {Total Expense xxxxxxx  \\
       Consumables - xxxxxxxx\\
       Travel - xxxxxxxx}\\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]